# Traefik truncated file

Tags: kubernetes, traefik-ingress

I have deployed a kubernetes cluster with 3 nodes. To create ingress, I am using Traefik.

When I tried to do a request, the web application is incompleted, some files are truncated and the web page cannot be load.

I have done the next test:

1 nodePort: it works (the web page is completed).

2 service: it works (the web page is completed).

3 ingress: it truncated files (some files are incompleted).

can someone help me? please

thank you in advance.

Best regard.

Comment: can you provide more details: how you configured Traefik, size of page you are trying to open, maybe screenshots of failed page. If you can - provide pieces of your configuration - someone from community might want to reproduce your issue in order to provide high quality  advice

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the trouble.

HaProxy was in mode HTTP, the attribute has been changed to mode tcp.

the trouble disappears.

Thank you very much.